# AKPlayer buffer mode set buffer size

Tags: ios, audiokit

IS there a way to set AKPlayers audio buffer size? Right now I am loading 144 sounds and it takes 1GB on the memory because by default AKPlayer loads all the file to the memory. I would like to load 2048 samples for each sound and decode as the sound is played.

I tried:

```
let drumFile = try AKAudioFile(readFileName: "0.aac")

var drums = AKPlayer()
drums.isLooping = true
drums.buffering = .always

try drums.load(url: drumFile.url)

drums.buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: AVAudioFormat(
    commonFormat: .pcmFormatInt32,
    sampleRate: 44100,
    channels: AVAudioChannelCount(2),
    interleaved: true
)!, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(2048))


drums.play()
```

but my app crashes on the buffer set line.

How may I set the buffer size of AKPlayer?